# Why does ES show an error log `readiness probe failed`?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am deploying Elasticsearch cluster on AWS EKS. Below is the k8s spec yml file.

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: datasource
spec:
  version: 7.14.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: node
    count: 3
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: true
      xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: false
      xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: false
      xpack.security.enabled: false
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
        - name: sysctl
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          command: ['sh', '-c', 'sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144']
        containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          readinessProbe:
              exec:
                command:
                - bash
                - -c
                - /mnt/elastic-internal/scripts/readiness-probe-script.sh
              failureThreshold: 3
              initialDelaySeconds: 10
              periodSeconds: 12
              successThreshold: 1
              timeoutSeconds: 12
          env:
          - name: READINESS_PROBE_TIMEOUT
            value: "30"
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: ebs-sc
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1024Gi
```

After deploy, I see all three pods have error:

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:19:37,041Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.m.MetadataMappingService", "cluster.name": "datasource", "node.name": "datasource-es-node-0", "message": "[.kibana/g5_90XpHSI-y-I7MJfBZhQ] update_mapping [_doc]", "cluster.uuid": "xJ00drroT_CbJPfzi8jSAg", "node.id": "qmtgUZHbR4aTWsYaoIEDEA"  }
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:19:37,622Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService", "cluster.name": "datasource", "node.name": "datasource-es-node-0", "message": "Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.kibana][0]]]).", "cluster.uuid": "xJ00drroT_CbJPfzi8jSAg", "node.id": "qmtgUZHbR4aTWsYaoIEDEA"  }
{"timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:19:40+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "35"}
{"timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:19:45+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "35"}
{"timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:19:50+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "35"}
{"timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:19:55+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "35"}
{"timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:20:00+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "35"}
{"timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:20:05+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "35"}
{"timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:20:10+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "35"}
{"timestamp": "2021-10-05T05:20:15+00:00", "message": "readiness probe failed", "curl_rc": "35"}
```

From above log, it shows `Cluster health status changed from [YELLOW] to [GREEN]`  first then comes to this error `readiness probe failed`. I wonder how I can solve this issue. Is it Elasticsearch related error or k8s related?

Comment: Judging from `node.store.allow_mmap` is set, presumed you are running all 3 pods on same worker node for experiment? If so you can try increase the readiness probe from 5 seconds to 30s.

Comment: I have 3 nodes and it is up to k8s to decide which node the es pod is running on. Does it allow me to update `readiness probe` when I use `elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1`? Checked their doc but doesn't seem to support this configuration: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/1.0/k8s-elasticsearch-k8s-elastic-co-v1.html#elasticsearch-k8s-elastic-co-v1-elasticsearchspec

Answer (score 1):

You should set **READINESS_PROBE_PROTOCOL** as '*http*'.

For example:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: data
spec:
  version: 7.15.2
  nodeSets:
  - name: data
    count: 1
    config:
      node.remote_cluster_client: false
      xpack.ml.enabled: false
      xpack.security.enabled: false
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: elasticsearch
          env:
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: -Xms1g -Xmx1g
          - name: READINESS_PROBE_TIMEOUT
            value: "30"
          - name: READINESS_PROBE_PROTOCOL
            value: http
```

Answer (score 0):

You can by declaring READINESS_PROBE_TIMEOUT in your spec like [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-readiness.html).

```
...
env:
- name: READINESS_PROBE_TIMEOUT
  value: "30"
```

You can customize the readiness probe if necessary, the latest `elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1 API` spec is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-api-elasticsearch-k8s-elastic-co-v1.html#k8s-api-github-com-elastic-cloud-on-k8s-pkg-apis-elasticsearch-v1-nodeset), it's the same K8s PodTemplateSpec that you can use in your `Elasticsearch` spec.

Update: curl error code 35 refers to SSL error. Here's a [post regarding the script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69466911/14704799). Can you remove the following settings from your spec and re-run:

```
xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: false
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: false
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Comment: I have tried and but still get the same error. I have updated the latest spec in my question.

Comment: The default protocol for readiness probe uses https, checkout the updated answer and give it a try?

Comment: I get this error if I remove these configuration: `received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/10.0.2.155:9200, remoteAddress=/10.0.2.237:40206`.

Comment: This error is related to the SSL certificates which by default will be provided by ECK, or did you specify your own own certificates? Suggest re-create the cluster with the updated spec.

Comment: No I don't have certificate. All the traffic is running inside VPC which is on http only. Is there a way to make it work in http?

Comment: TLS is a [reserved setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-reserved-settings.html) by ECK. Btw, the readiness probe error gone away?

Comment: yes, there is no probe error. Not sure whether it is gone or it fails before readiness check. So does it mean we can't use http anymore?